# Android: build.gradle error when adding firebase requirements

Tags: android, firebase, gradle

When I follow the firebase instructions and added:

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
```

to the `dependencies` and:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.0.0'
```

to the `dependencies` as well, the all of a sudden I get an error on this line in the `dependencies`:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
```

Here is the error message:

`Dependencies using groupId com.android.support and androidx.* can not be combined but found IdeMavenCoordinates{myGroupId='com.android.support', myArtifactId='animated-vector-drawable', myVersion='27.1.1', myPacking='aar', myClassifier='null'} and IdeMavenCoordinates{myGroupId='androidx.lifecycle', myArtifactId='lifecycle-viewmodel', myVersion='2.0.0', myPacking='aar', myClassifier='null'} incompatible dependencies less... (⌘F1) 
Inspection info:There are some combinations of libraries, or tools and libraries, that are incompatible, or can lead to bugs. One such incompatibility is compiling with a version of the Android support libraries that is not the latest version (or in particular, a version lower than your targetSdkVersion).`

What shall I do? Why this happened after adding firebase?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Appcompat error with firebase library implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56794619/appcompat-error-with-firebase-library-implementation)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(*EDIT: THIS IS AN IMPROVED ANSWER OF THE ORIGINAL ANSWER WHICH IS GOT DELETED DUE TO CERTAIN ISSUES.*)

Firebase migrated to AndroidX in the latest release. Which means that,

> AndroidX maps the original support library API packages into the
>   androidx namespace. Only the package and Maven artifact names changed;
>   class, method, and field names did not change.

So latest firebase releases no longer supports for the old support libraries. You have to either downgrade firebase with,

`implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.9'`

or migrate your app to use AndroidX as mentioned below.(**Anyway** if your app depends on any `com.google.android.gms` or `com.google.firebase` libraries, you should prepare for this migration)

> This release is a MAJOR version update and includes breaking changes.
>   With this release, libraries are migrated from the Android Support
>   Libraries to the Jetpack (AndroidX) Libraries. The updated libraries
>   will not work unless you make the following changes in your app:
>
> Upgrade com.android.tools.build:gradle to v3.2.1 or later.
>
> Upgrade compileSdkVersion to 28 or later.
>
> Update your app to use Jetpack
>   (AndroidX); follow the instructions in Migrating to [AndroidX.](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate)

With Android Studio 3.2 and higher, migration is lot easier. selecting **Refactor > Migrate** to AndroidX from the menu bar we can migrate to AndroidX.

And any maven dependencies can be handled as on below,

> Maven dependencies that have not been migrated to the AndroidX
>   namespace, the Android Studio build system also migrates those
>   dependencies for you when you set the following two flags to true in
>   your gradle.properties file:
>
> ```
> android.useAndroidX=true
> android.enableJetifier=true
> ```
>
> To migrate an existing project that does not use any third-party
>   libraries with dependencies that need converting, you can set the
>   android.useAndroidX flag to true and the android.enableJetifier flag
>   to false.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Actually downgrading the firebase as you suggested worked. Is there any downside for downgrading?

Comment: For my use case, i have not met with any issue so far with downgrading. But of course we miss all the fixes and new feature that might include in a latest release. Anyway, migrating to AndroidX libraries might be more suitable regarding future as well.