# Appcompat error with firebase library implementation

Tags: android, firebase, build.gradle, android-appcompat

Hello I had a little question about adding dependency for firebase. when I add this line: `implementation 'com.google.firebase: firebase-core: 17.0.0'` to my buil.gradle I see an error line at the line: `implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat -v7: 28.0.0`. I searched but not yet a solution. Thank you for helping me.

Comment: add your error log as text or screen

Comment: Do you use android studio firebase tool as http://prntscr.com/o7kfpn?

Answer (score 3):

Firebase migrated to AndroidX in the latest release. So no more supports for the old support libraries. You have to either downgrade firebase,

`implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.9'`

or migrate your app to use AndroidX as mentioned below.

> This release is a MAJOR version update and includes breaking changes.
>   With this release, libraries are migrated from the Android Support
>   Libraries to the Jetpack (AndroidX) Libraries. The updated libraries
>   will not work unless you make the following changes in your app:
>
> Upgrade com.android.tools.build:gradle to v3.2.1 or later.
>
> Upgrade compileSdkVersion to 28 or later.
>
> Update your app to use Jetpack
>   (AndroidX); follow the instructions in Migrating to [AndroidX.](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate)

Comment: Thank for your help Anjana. i have done these upgrades. But i have again this error : ERROR: Failed to resolve: com.google
Affected Modules: app